# How can I load server data into bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap modal component submit button calls server and retrieves the data. Now I need to show the data into another modal component.

My code:
index.html

## calling code for firstmodal:

```
<a href="#" class="#link-to" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditModal">Edit Button Employee</a>
   <div id="myEditModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myEditModal" data-dismiss="modal">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <div class="modal-body">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
             <br/><br/>
             <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label" for="value">Employee Id:</label>
               <div class="controls"> 
                 {{input type="text" class="input-medium" value=id }}
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "editIdAction" target="controller" }}>Save</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

## in app.js:

```
 editIdAction: function () {
                  var id = this.get('id');
                  var controller = this;
                  data = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "/editid?id=" + id,
                    async: false}).responseJSON;
                    console.log(data)
                    controller.set("id", "");
                    this.transitionToRoute('editprofile', data)
    }
```

Now how can I forward route to modal.

And I create another modal with `id = editprofile`, but it is not working. the modal is not popup.

I search in google and I found modal to modal interaction.

But I didn't find response modal to modal.

Could someone help?

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you tell your code to open up the modal?

Comment: i added calling code and updated